# Can I have camel case as default when using postgres in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

If you don't specify anything all the fields are created as lower case in the database when using postgres. Is it possible to change the default behavior to use the exact name of the fields in the model? That makes it easier to write custom queries.

As it is now I have to configure the property on each field to say that they should be camel case, and that is quite error prone since that is something that is easy to forget.

If that isn't possible, is it possible to use the functionality in the repository that does the mapping from all lowercase to the fields in the models in an easy manner somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can use name property
example:

```
 export class User extends .... {   @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,   })   id?: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    name: 'first_name',
  })   
  firstName: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    name: 'last_name',
  })
  lastName: string;
```

Comment: got from here... https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-starter